# How do access native APIs with Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

If I wanted to create a mobile app that allows the user to take pictures with their phone, record audio notes and record video, how would I do that?

I was browsing through the Sencha Touch 2 API and while I see documentation on video and audio files, it seems like it is just providing a way for me to access files stored on the phone - not actual triggers to record, or take pictures.

Am I missing something?

How would I do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for Sencha Touch to have access to your phone capabilities, you need to use a product like [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: AFAIK, PhoneGap is the only Framework known to man that supports Sencha Touch. Please correct me.

Comment: Can I correct you by saying that you are not incorrect, afaik? =P

Comment: @nisc - I believe nimblekit is another native wrapper framework, though I have never used it, PhoneGap is great. See http://www.sencha.com/learn/enhancing-ios-sencha-touch-apps-with-nimblekit

Comment: Interesting, but looks like it only does iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a HTML5 api for doing those sorts of things I don't think you can do that.  I know on PhoneGap there are native extensions added into that platform for access to things like microphone, camera, etc.  I don't know if Sencha Touch has added any of those sorts of extensions in order for you do this.

Just thinking out of the box here, but you might be able to put Sencha javascript into a Web View from within an Android Java process.  Then the Java code could expose an object in its process as an extension point to the Javascript engine for access to Camera, Microphone, what not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's way too much work for what I want to do. I will look into Phone Gap for that.